# What is the purpose of base-package in aapt

Tags: android, r.java-file

The title is self explanatory.

aapt help shows that there is an option called `[-I base-package]`. what is the use of this option.
And how is `base-package` different than `custom-package`.

Any Ideas..?

And is this possible to package some (not all) `R$` classes like (`R$drawable`, etc) to a different package.

Thanks.